# $x f'$ bounded by $x^2f $ and $f''$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, hilbert-spaces

Consider the Hilbert space of functions $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that $x^2f \in L^2(\mathbb R) $ and $ f'' \in L^2(\mathbb R).$

I am wondering whether it is true that $xf'\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ as well?

It seems natural and perhaps some sort of interpolation should yield the claim but I fail to see how to show this.

Comment: $L^2$ of $\bf R$, presumably?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies that's right.

Comment: There's probably also a highbrow explanation for this, along the following lines: Your assumptions say that $f$ is in the natural domain of the (harmonic oscillator) operator $Lf=-f''+x^2f$, which can be factored as $L=A^*A$, $A=D+x$, and this should also imply the claim. (The more elementary answers seem more appropriate though.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By a cutoff function argument, it suffices to assume $f$ is compactly supported, so we can integrate by parts without picking up boundary terms.

Thus
$$\int (xf')^2 = \int (x^2f') f' = -\int 2xf'f - \int x^2 f'' f$$
Hence using Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\|xf'\|_2^2 \le \int |2xf f'| + \int |x^2 f f''| \le 2\|xf\|_2 \|f'\|_2 + \|x^2f\|_2 \|f''\|_2.$$
The second term is finite by our assumption.  For the first term, note that
$$\|xf\|_2^2 = \int x^2 f^2 = \int |x^2f| |f| \le \|x^2f\|_2 \|f\|_2$$
and 
$$\|f'\|^2 = \int (f')^2 = -\int f f'' \le \int |f f''| \le \|f\|_2 \|f''\|_2.$$

Putting everything together, we have
$$\|xf'\|_2^2 \le 2 \|f\|_2 \sqrt{\|f''\|_2 \|x^2f\|_2} + \|x^2f\|_2 \|f''\|_2.$$

Answer (score 15):

By integration by parts,
$$\int (xf')^2 = \int (x^2f') f' = -\int 2xf'f - \int x^2 f'' f.$$
$$-\int 2xf'f = \int f^2=\|f\|^2.$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\bigg|\int x^2 f'' f\bigg|\le \|x^2f\|\|f''\|.$$
The conclusion is proved.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's much better than mine.  (Hint to people as slow as me: in the second line, $2f'f = (f^2)'$.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: You are too kind. :-)